# Python - append JSON into main branch

Tags: python, json

Maybe I am too stuck to see the simple solution for the following problem:

Given:

```
import json
a = {
  "24631331976_defa3bb61f_k.jpg668058":{
  "regions": {
      "0": {},
      "1": {}
      }
  }
}

b = {
  "16335852991_f55de7958d_k.jpg1767935":{
  "regions": {
      "0": {}
      }
  }
}
```

I want to append them in order to get the following output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiMeQ.png)

Thanks to Daniel Hepper and SegFault, the problem could be solved with:

```
a.update(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = {}
c.update(a)
c.update(b)
```

Alternatively, if you are fine with modifying `a`:

```
a.update(b)
```

Note that your code uses Python dictionaries, not JSON strings.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'append' a dict to another one, simply because the `append` add element  to the end of an ordered list of elements.

`dict`s don't have the notion of order, fist or last element. Thus no `append` for dict.

The action you want to do is `merging` two `dict`s, and you can do that using the `update` method defined for the `dict` type.

```
a.update(b)
```

PS: that will modify the dict `a`